# The presence of Angels when uncovered (source)

Tags: sources-mekorot, malach-angel

I can't remember exactly where I read this, but is it true that angels are not present when someone is uncovered? Is there a source for this?

Comment: It seems like the Gemara brought below supports the idea. However, it's very possible that it's not what you read

Answer (score 2):

[Berachot 60b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Berakhot.60b?lang=bi):

> הַנִּכְנָס לְבֵית הַכִּסֵּא, אוֹמֵר: ״הִתְכַּבְּדוּ מְכוּבָּדִים קְדוֹשִׁים מְשָׁרְתֵי עֶלְיוֹן, תְּנוּ כָּבוֹד לֵאלֹהֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל, הַרְפּוּ מִמֶּנִּי עַד שֶׁאֶכָּנֵס וְאֶעֱשֶׂה רְצוֹנִי וְאָבֹא אֲלֵיכֶם״. אָמַר אַבָּיֵי: לָא לֵימָא אִינָשׁ הָכִי, דִּלְמָא שָׁבְקִי לֵיהּ וְאָזְלִי. אֶלָּא לֵימָא: ״שִׁמְרוּנִי שִׁמְרוּנִי, עִזְרוּנִי עִזְרוּנִי, סִמְכוּנִי סִמְכוּנִי, הַמְתִּינוּ לִי הַמְתִּינוּ לִי עַד שֶׁאֶכָּנֵס וְאֵצֵא, שֶׁכֵּן דַּרְכָּן שֶׁל בְּנֵי אָדָם״.
>
> One who enters a bathroom says [to the angels who accompany him at all times]:
> Be honored, honorable holy ones, servants of the [One] on High,
> give honor to the God of Israel,
> leave me until I enter and do my will and come [back] to you.
> Abaye said: A person should not say this, lest they abandon him and go. Rather he should say:
> Guard me, guard me,
> help me, help me,
> support me, support me,
> wait for me, wait for me until I enter and come out, as this is the way of man.

Comment: Does this have to do with being uncovered in the bathroom or the bathroom itself?